# chmod: changing permissions of directory Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, centos, command-line, permissions, chmod

I have done

```
chmod -R 644 .
```

inside the directory *dir*

My user's permissions are *drw-r--r--* and i'm the owner of the directory

When trying chmod 755 dir, error is popped

> chmod: changing permissions of dir Operation not permitted

The same error is popped when doing *ls* even as root

How to change permission back to 755 and allow its deletion and modification?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

from the level above *dir*:

```
chmod -R a+x *dir*
```

to give all users (a) execute permission to all subdirectories and files (+x) or:

```
chmod -R a+X *dir*
```

to give all users execute permission to all subdirectories only (+X)

Comment: Coincidently I didn't know that you selectively ignore files by using capital X until i started reading up to give you an answer!

Comment: Haha, my bad! I'm still waking up

Comment: This gives execute permissions to all below *dir* to all users. You may not want that. There is another answer here which gives it only to directories (find dir -type d -exec ...). IMHO that is a better solution.

Comment: For me, the problem was just preceding the command with `sudo`. Trivial, but should be stated.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've broken a tree of directory permissions with `chmod -R` you need to fix them all up. Run this from the directory above `dir`:

```
find dir -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,go=rx {} +
find dir \! -type d -exec chmod u=rw,go=r {} +
```

In case you're wondering, you need the `x` permission to access a directory. You need `rx` to be able to read it.

For those with a modern (GNU) version of `chmod` you may be able to do this all in one step. Symbolically this equates to "everyone (group/other) has the same as the owner, but remove write permissions from group/other"

```
chmod -R a=u,go-w dir
```

Comment: Can you explain what's with the '\!'? The rest looks familiar.

Comment: @SybillePeters the `!` means `not`. It is a special character for some shells, and so needs to be single-quoted or escaped with a backslash so that the shell doesn't try to process it.

Comment: Of course! It's obvious now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

[image]Hello, I think I have a solution to your problem. Here is the problem:

```
chmod 777
```

You did not put sudo so try putting sudo in like this:

```
sudo chmod 777
```

Comment: 1. Permissions 777 give full control to everyone. Do you really want other users to be able to edit or even delete your files? 2. If they're your files you don't need `sudo`